# Why does this return -2

Tags: powershell

I am trying to follow a tutorial and I don't understand why this returns -2. The script works and does everything it's supposed to do, but the console outputs -2. Can't figure out why. Any ideas?

There are no errors that print out to the console. Just the -2.

```
param($FirstName,$MiddleInitial,$LastName,$Location = 'OU=Corporate Users',$Title)

$DefaultPassword = 'p@$$word12'
$DomainDn = (Get-ADDomain).DistinguishedName
$DefaultGroup = 'Gigantic Corporation Inter-Intra Synergy Group'

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
### Figure out what the username should be
###

$Username = "$($FirstName.SubString(0,1))$LastName"

$EaPrefBefore = $ErrorActionPreference 
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

    if (Get-ADUser $Username) {
        $Username = "$($FirstName.SubString(0,1))$MiddleInitial$LastName"

        if (Get-ADUser $Username) {
            Write-Warning "No acceptable username schema could be created"
            return
        }
    }


### ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
### Create the user account 
###

$ErrorActionPreference - $EaPrefBefore
$NewUserParams = @{
    'UserPrincipalName' = $Username
    'Name' = $Username
    'GivenName' = $FirstName
    'Surname' = $LastName
    'Title' = $Title
    'SamAccountName' = $Username
    'AccountPassword' = (ConvertTo-SecureString $DefaultPassword -AsPlainText -Force)
    'Enabled' = $true
    'Initials' = $MiddleInitial
    'Path' = "$Location,$DomainDn"
    'ChangePasswordAtLogon' = $true
}

New-ADUser @NewUserParams

### ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
### Add the user account to the company standard group
###

Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $DefaultGroup -Members $Username
```

Like I said, it works and does whatever it's supposed to do. The new user is created and the user is sent to the group, all the rules work fine. But it returns -2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a value is returned by an expression in PowerShell and not assigned to a variable, it's printed to the console. Looks like this is coming from your line
`$ErrorActionPreference - $EaPrefBefore`, which just subtracts two codes and doesn't do anything with the result. I think you meant to use an equals sign (`=`) instead of minus here.